# Cannot disable ASP.NET request validation for URL "/x:)"

Tags: asp.net, .net, request-validation

When I access the URL `/x:)` of my ASP.NET MVC 5 app I get this error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:). 

[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9939892
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53
```

This is the full stack trace.

I want to disable request validation entirely. I don't need it and I need to process even strange URLs like this one.

I have applied all of these settings but they did not work:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

How can I avoid request validation entirely?

Comment: have you tried a IIS request filtering feature?

Comment: @NegiRox I created a new web app just for testing purposes. All I did was add these settings and add a route. That new application does not use IIS request filtering. So that feature can't be the reason for the error.

Comment: you are trying to avoid that type of request?

Comment: No, I want to process it without error.

Comment: is it asp.net MVC pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow special characters in your URL path you should modify the requestPathInvalidCharacters parameter in web.config like this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
</system.web>
```

Note, I've just removed the asterisk (*), the original default string is:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
```

Comment: This was it. I now set it to `""` to disable these checks entirely.